# Asynchronous request on bootstrap AngularJS uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to search on the server side a name entered by the user, and give suggestions using bootstrap 3 [uib-typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead), however (although I hard coded the values to return - for testing purposes), no value is returning to the typeahead dropdown. My guess is that since this is an async request, any data is already returned by the time the request data is retrieved.

Is there any way how data could be retrieved from server side, whilst typeahead is listening?

```js
$scope.test_search = function(test_name){
    var curr_url = '/plan/ajax/test/';

    var search_response =  $http.get(curr_url,{
        cache: true,
        params:{'name': test_name, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $cookies.csrftoken}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        //return response.data;
        var test = [
            {country: "US", name : 'Alabama'}
        ];
        return test;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert('Error');
    });

},
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <pre>Model: {{new_ingredient_selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text"
           ng-model = "new_ingredient_selected"
           placeholder="test test"
           uib-typeahead="ingredient.name for ingredient in test_search($viewValue) |  filter:{name:$viewValue}"
           typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
           typeahead-no-results="noResults"
           typeahead-on-select="onTypeaheadIngredientSelect($item, $label, $index)"
           typeahead-wait-ms ="400"
           class="form-control">

    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test_search` function needs a [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement:

```
$scope.test_search = function(test_name){
    var curr_url = '/plan/ajax/test/';

    var search_response =  $http.get(curr_url,{
        cache: true,
        params:{'name': test_name, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $cookies.csrftoken}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        //return response.data;
        var test = [
            {country: "US", name : 'Alabama'}
        ];
        return test;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert('Error');
        //IMPORTANT
        //RE-THROW the error
        ͟t͟h͟r͟o͟w͟ ͟r͟e͟s͟p͟o͟n͟s͟e͟;͟
    });

    //IMPORTANT
    //RETURN the promise
    ͟ ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ ͟s͟e͟a͟r͟c͟h͟_͟r͟e͟s͟p͟o͟n͟s͟e͟;͟

};
```

When a function lacks a [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement, it returns a value of `undefined`.

Also it is important to [re-throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) the error response in the rejection handler. Otherwise the rejected promise will be **converted** to a fulfilled promise that resolves with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: Resolved the problem by awaiting the callback from the async request and then returning the retrieved data.