# AngularJS uib-typeahead not updating list of values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following uib-typeahead markup:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_location" ng-model="surveyData.location"
     placeholder="Search"
     uib-typeahead="location as location.name for location in newListLocations | filter:$viewValue:customSearch | orderBy:location.country.name | limitTo:200"
     typeahead-editable="false">
```

And I update it with a REST call that works perfectly in the back-end, and here's how I consume it in the controller (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497696/asynchronous-request-on-bootstrap-angularjs-uib-typeahead)):

```
$scope.filterLocations = function(searchValue, viewValue) {
     var newListOfLocations = LocationTypeaheadFilter.queryWithTypeaheadSearchValue(viewValue).then(function (list){
     $scope.newListLocations = list.data;
     console.log($scope.newListLocations);
     return $scope.newListLocations;
     },
     function errorCallback(response) {
         alert('Error');
         throw response;
     });
       return newListOfLocations;
};
```

This function is called using this the original one from the markup:

```
$scope.customSearch = function(searchValue, viewValue){
               return $scope.filterLocations(searchValue, viewValue);}
```

I tried at first putting all the logic in one same method, but no difference, the list for the typeahead always turns up empty, even though when I log it on console in the `.then` area, it shows all values I expect it to hold.

I've tried a number of different ways, but I believe that it should work the way I've coded it, provided I'm waiting for the callback

**EDIT** to add the factory where I defined the Angular service:

```
.factory('LocationTypeaheadFilter', function ($http, DateUtils) {
        return {
            queryWithTypeaheadSearchValue: function(query){
                return $http.get("api/locationssearchTypeahead/"+query)
            }
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using `location as location.name`, then later in the same expression you're using `orderBy:location.country.name`. Is `location.name` a valid path?

Did you mean `location as location.country.name`? Getting this wrong would result in a blank list.

If you could add a sample of the location data to your question, that would help find what's going wrong.